# Modal dialog present Exception

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I try to click on `a` element, by this way:

```
WebElement title = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()=\"Delete this document library\"]"));
title.click();
```

When I click on it manually, its opens a window:

```
The page at http://.. says
Are you sure you want to delete the selected items?
```

with `OK` and `Cancel` buttons

But when I run it with WebDriver (in `Firefox 20.0`), I get the next error:

```
[Exception]: Modal dialog present
```

and I don't see even the window.

What can be the reason?

Answer (score 4):

You don't see the Alert when you run the test is because the default behavior of the `WebDriver` is that it *accepts alert* when the *Modal dialog present exception is thrown*. It happens so fast that you can't see the alert.

```
  WebElement title = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()=\"Delete this document library\"]"));
title.click();

//Now the alert appears. 
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
alert.accept();
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what Mark Rowlands suggest in his link. It doesn't do anything (I need to perss OK in this alert). How I change the Firefox which would not accepts alert and will show it?

Comment: Write the code in the answer, it switches to the alert once the alert appears and click ok button on the alert. You will no longer see Modal dialog present exception.

Answer (score 3):

If an alert window doesn't appear every time, you could do this:

```
try { 
    Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
    alert.accept();
    //if alert present, accept and move on.
}
catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {
    //do what you normally would if you didn't have the alert.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're encountering an `Alert`.

Do this help?

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Q:_Does_WebDriver_support_Javascript_alerts_and_prompts?

Comment: It's not opening at all?

Answer (score 0):

alert.dismiss() or or Press Esc button you can dismiss the alert. For my case for this is solved this issue.

Comment: Could you please be a bit more specific?

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath("...");
    Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
    alert.dismiss();
OR
    Robot r = new Robot();
    r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);
    r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);

Comment: Not in a comment, please update your post. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer on how to write a "good" answer.